# Navigation Menu: Add custom markup element

Tags: zend-framework2, navigationbar

I'm using Zend/Navigation in Zend Framework 2. It prints this:

```
<ul class="Navigation">
    <li>
       <a href="">Home Page</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But i want to put a `<span>` element inside every `<li>` like this:

```
<ul class="Navigation">
    <li>
        <span>
           <a href="">Home Page</a>
       </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
           <a href="">Contact</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to do that without using a "partial" solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no other way, how to change html output from menu view helper (except indentation and `<ul>` class).

Well, of course, you can write your own menu view helper - extend `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu` and override htmlify method:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.2.5/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/Menu.php#L472,
but I think, partial template is much better and easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is intrested this guy has created a helper doing this job. http://cmyker.blogspot.gr/2012/11/zend-framework-2-navigation-menu-to.html